# Manipulating html canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

Is there any way to get raw canvas data? I don't want pixel ones from getImageData(). I would think of something like history of what was drawn on canvas. Some structure of objects representing each drawing to canvas.

Comment: I might be wrong but I think there's no function for that. I would just create an array(or arrays) of the stuff I draw on the canvas. That's how I work with my current project.

Comment: There's [`save()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save) and [`restore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore), but they just keep track of state. Not what was drawn.

Comment: Thank you, I also found toDataURL(), my intentions are to create extension to chrome which will monitor changes in canvas and compare them to desired results, but I'd like to be able more than just say if the result differs from my goal or not, I'd like to see if the difference is huge (e.g. wrong element inserted) or for example if just text was inserted compare that text etc..